# How should I define my XSD to have dynamic types used as elements?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am defining a XSD schema for the SOAP requests to be sent to a Web Service that accepts requests like these:

```
<generic.GenericObject.configureInstanceWithResult xmlns="xmlapi_1.0">
    [..]
    <configInfo>
        <lte.Cell>
            <actionMask>
                <bit>modify</bit>
            </actionMask>
            <spare1>1</spare1>
        </lte.Cell>
    </configInfo>
</generic.GenericObject.configureInstanceWithResult>
<generic.GenericObject.configureInstanceWithResult xmlns="xmlapi_1.0">
    [...]
    <configInfo>
        <lte.LteNeighboringCellRelation>
            <actionMask>
                <bit>modify</bit>
            </actionMask>
            <cellIndividualOffset>-1</cellIndividualOffset>
        </lte.LteNeighboringCellRelation>
    </configInfo>
</generic.GenericObject.configureInstanceWithResult>
```

In order to achieve this result, I have tried with this schema definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="xmlapi_1.0" xmlns:tns="xmlapi_1.0" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<complexType name="Generic.GenericObject.configureInstanceWithResult">
    <sequence>
        [...]
        <element name="configInfo" type="tns:ConfigInfo" />
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="ConfigInfo">
    <sequence>
        <element name="payload" type="anyType" />
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="lte.Cell">
    <sequence>
        <element name="spare" type="string" />
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="lte.LteNeighboringCellRelation">
    <sequence>
        <element name="qOffsetCell" type="string" />
        <element name="cellIndividualOffset" type="string" />
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<element name="generic.GenericObject.configureInstanceWithResult" type="tns:Generic.GenericObject.configureInstanceWithResult" />
```

But the result I get is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<generic.GenericObject.configureInstanceWithResult xmlns="xmlapi_1.0">
    <configInfo>
        <payload xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="lte.Cell">
            <spare>-1</spare>
        </payload>
    </configInfo>
</generic.GenericObject.configureInstanceWithResult>
```

Do you see any way in which I could have `xsi:type="lte.Cell"` as `<lte.Cell>` instead of `<payload>`?

Note: Using `anyType` in ConfigInfo is no good as `<configInfo>` gets removed and the request is no longer compliant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, I think that they best approach here is to have `any` as element in `<ConfigInfo>`:

```
<complexType name="ConfigInfo">
    <sequence>
       <any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

This allows you to have any type of object marked with `@XmlRootElement`introduced in your XML.

In this particular case where I had two classes defined in the schema as eligible for "payload", element declarations need to be introduced so they are marked correctly as `@XmlRootElement`:

```
<element name="lte.Cell" type="tns:Lte.Cell" />
<element name="lte.LteNeighboringCellRelation" type="tns:Lte.LteNeighboringCellRelation" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make payload into a global element declaration (preferably with abstract="true"), and create element declarations for lte.Cell and lte.LteNeighboringCellRelation that specify substitutionGroup="payload".

Comment: Thanks Michael. I was considering that option but the problem is that you have to specify the types of objects being used as "payload". The problem here is that this object is the base of an "API" to configure a large number of different types so is better if we do something truly dynamic (without hardcoding anything). I am currently trying a solution using "xs:any" and marking every element with @XMLRootElement that I think is going to work fine.